# private npm module works locally but not as a published node_module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader, antd, npm-publish

I have created a private npm module that works perfectly fine when I run the application locally. It also successfully publishes when I use `npm publish`. However, it is dependent on the library antd and if I leave it in depedencies, it will say that it cannot find antd@2.12.1. So I moved it into peerDependencies and then it would install. When I try to import any component (I started with the simplest just as a test case) from my successfully installed npm package, it would throw this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| const Module = ({children}) => (
|   <span className=`module-title`>{children}</span>
| )
|
```

The above loader issue shows up regardless of whether or not it is a module that uses antd or not. My application is using webpack. The module: loaders section of my webpack can be found below:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        // include: /node_modules\/@nuralogix\/dfx-ui\/src/
      },
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        // include: /node_modules\/@nuralogix\/dfx-ui\/src/
      },
      { test: /\.global\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      { test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      { test: /\.global\.less$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ]
      },
      { test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.less$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ]
      },
```

The comment out of `include:` has been helpful in the past but currently causes errors.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas about why I cannot use this modules (despite its seeming simplicity).

Babel file for reference:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": { "node": 7 },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-optimize"],
      "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-dev-expression",
          ["import", {"libraryName": "antd", "style": true}]
      ]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-es2015-classes",
          ["import", {"libraryName": "antd", "style": true} ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: I am extremely confident that I am not compile down to es5 properly. I have add these two scripts and installed the relevant files for them in my package.json

```
"compile": "rimraf lib/* && babel src -d lib",
"prepare": "npm run compile"
```

Now, I get this error:

```
sh: 1: babel: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! packageName compile: 'rimraf lib/* && babel src -d lib'
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

My .babelrc file is the same as above except I added:

```
"transform-runtime",
```

To both dev and prod.

Does anyone have experience creating scripts for compiling es6 to es5 using rimraf or anything else?

For reference, I am basing much of the new additions on this article:

http://blog.xebia.com/publishing-es6-code-to-npm/

Comment: this usually means your babel is not properly setup with right plugins or env, have you check that?

Comment: I have included my babel above, I am not sure what I am missing. Just for the sake of it, I tried placing my dev plugins into prod but that changed nothing.

Comment: I had this problem before,  the reason is for some how a small part of the code doesn't transpile into es5, so that makes when you publish it, it will not work. my problem was we had some package  version mis aligned, make sure yarn/npm does not report any package dependancy warning

Comment: @Kossel I think you are right, when I install the package, I checked and just about everything was still in es6. I have another project that is compiling just fine back down to es5 but I always forgot which package manages that. Can you recommend anything?

Comment: remove node_module folder, do npm install, make sure there no warnings like "xxx has unmet version" looks like when that happen babel would just refuse to transpile for that package.

Comment: @Kossel I did some package.json reorganization and reinstallations. I had zero warnings or errors when installing locally. When I installed the newly published package in another project I received a list of warnings and when I ran the app, it brought up the same loader error. Many of them are asking for various older versions of React (which are out of the question) for packages that I am not using (so I assume they are in antd) I have and am using antd in the project I installed it within without errors). One of them even want jquery 1.8.0 oddly enough.

Comment: @Kossel in case if you are interested, I added some new information to my question regarding compilation errors from es6 - es5 since I am confident that that is the core of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, in fact.

Create `.npmignore` in the root folder, add sources to ignore list, e.g.

```
/src
/node_modules
.git
```